# RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to hit an API, and get data with requests module in python.

I am using `conn.request("POST", "/middleware/application/servicegateway/Publicis/XXX/calculatetax", payload, headers)`

```
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

This does print the response as `{"base_amount":40,"tax_percent":0.05,"total_tax":1.90476}`

But, when I try to put this response data into a variable,using

I get the error as,

```
RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

Complete code is as below :

```
def create_query (start_date, end_date):
    raw_query1 = "Select cnsmr_id as cnsmr_id_1, cnsmr_loc_id as loc_id_1 from staging.trvs_cnsmr where registration_date between '%s' and '%s' " %(start_date, end_date)
    red_engine = create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://YYYY:ZZZZZ@AA.BB.CC.DD:5000/DB')
    test1 = pd.read_sql_query(raw_query1,red_engine)
    for index1, row1 in test1.iterrows():
        print(row1['cnsmr_id_1'], row1['loc_id_1'])
        raw_query2 = "Select cnsmr_loc_id, state, cnsmr_loc_addrss_line_1, cnsmr_loc_addrss_line_2, city, country, zipcode from staging.trvs_consumer_loc1 where              cnsmr_loc_id =  '%s' and country = 'CAN ' " %(row1['loc_id_1'])
        test2 = pd.read_sql_query(raw_query2,red_engine)
        for index2, row2 in test2.iterrows():
            print(row2['cnsmr_loc_id'], row2['state'], row2['cnsmr_loc_addrss_line_1'], row2['cnsmr_loc_addrss_line_2'], row2['city'], row2['country'], row2['zipcode']             )
            raw_query3 = "Select subscription_id, cnsmr_id as cnsmr_id_2 , bus_id, payment_amount from staging.trvs_cnsmr_payment where cnsmr_id_2 = '%s' "  %(row1['cnsmr_id_1'])
            test3 = pd.read_sql_query(raw_query3,red_engine)
            for index3, row3 in test3.iterrows():
                print (row3['bus_id'], row3['payment_amount'], row3['subscription_id'], row3['cnsmr_id_2'], row2['zipcode'])
                payload = "{\n\"businessunit\":\"%s\", \"amount\":\"%d\", \"addresslineone\":\"%s\", \"addresslinetwo\":\"%s\", \"stateorprovince\":\"%s\",                           \"postcalcode\":\"%s\", \"city\":\"%s\", \"country\":\"%s\"\n}" %(row3['bus_id'], row3['payment_amount'], row2['cnsmr_loc_addrss_line_1'],                            row2['cnsmr_loc_addrss_line_2'], row2['state'], row2['zipcode'], row2['city'], row2['country'])
                headers = {"X-API-CLIENT-ID":"XXXX", "X-API-TOKEN":"5a98"}
                conn.request("POST", "/application/servicegateway/client/atn/taxation/calculatetax", payload, headers)
                res = conn.getresponse()
                data = res.read()
                print(data.decode("utf-8"))
                x = data.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: There seems to be some code missing in your question.

Comment: Pls find the complete code updated, although my question in specific is how to get the API Json data into a variable ?